# Declaration and usage of Output Variable in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a Continuous Integration pipeline that uses Bash script tasks in order to create the initial variables for runtime.

I have a variable that I call: `datebuild`, which is formatted accordingly : `$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)`.

Currently I'm using the pipeline variable that's how I'm declaring it[image: Pipeline variable declaration]
When using the `datebuild` variable under Bash@3 task, it successfully formatting it.

Afterwards I want to take the formatted output in order to use it on different tasks **inside one agent job**.

On the second task I need to copy file to the Artifact Staging Directory:

`20200423_141808` is the file and Artifact Staging Directory is the Destination Directory, for example.

[image: Output from copying files to artifact staging directory]

I've been reading that it can be used with feature called Output Variables.

Created the reference variable named: ref1, and on the task I want to take the output variable I'm using the `ref1.datebuild` in order to access the variable

Used the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) in order to use the output variable it doesn't seem to work.

here's the task inside the pipeline:

[image: Copy task@2]

Trying to understand What I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the formatted date and set it as a variable for the next steps in the job.

For example, in YAML pipeline:

```
variables:
  datebuild: '$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)'

steps:
- bash: |
   formated="$(datebuild)"
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=formatedDate]$formated"

- bash: |
   echo $(formatedDate)
```

In the editor:

[image]

The second bash task output is:

[image]

Comment: Hey I've tried this approach but there's one problem, that I'm taking a file that got created in one task and doing some operations on it, but in order for doing so I need to get the specific formatted date that got created by the first task, which means if its 000000_000001 and according to your approach on the following tasks it will take the formatted time, 000000_000010 for example.

Comment: You can set the variable to whatever you want, so instead of set the `formated` value you can edit it to what you need (000000_000001) and then set the variable.